# VBA odbc connection accessing a single library only

Tags: excel, odbc, ibm-midrange, vba

I have successfully connected to an as400 server. But whenever i execute an sql statement

```
select * from nosd0
```

It doesn't work, because nosd0 is in lib1/fil1(nosd0)

it gives an error saying nosd0 is not in lib2.

When I execute the query on STRSQL on as400 it works fine.

I tried creating an alias and it's malfunctioning. Please I really need some help on this one

---

Alias is working, I am accessing the wrong file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem, this will also help all those who wants to connect to their AS400 iSeries using VBA. ;)

My problem above is that when I try my Query on the box, it accesses lib1/nosd0, and in VBA, I was trying to get lib2/fil1(nosd0) which is a description of the table nosdo itself. The simple solution is to query

```
select * from lib1.nosd0
```

More on that when connecting to an AS400 iSeries using ODBC, there is a parameter called DBQ
[Connection String Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275047(v=bts.10).aspx)

My final connection string would be.

```
ConnectString = "Driver={ISeries Access ODBC Driver};System=" & DCServer(I) & ";Uid=--;Pwd=--;NAM=0;DBQ=lib1,*ALL;"
```